# creating multiple partitions

Tags: installation, partitioning

I am installing Ubuntu 12.04, just removed all the existing partitions which had earlier Windows Xp and Ubuntu 13.04. I am doing a fresh install now.

I want multiple drives, just in case I need them to save some media files, etc etc..

My laptop hardrive is of 320 GB

I have already created three partitions - swap for 4 GB, root (/) for 20 GB and /home for 10GB and I have still a free space of 280GB. What next for me? Should I increase /home

and how to create some additional drives/partitions. any help will be helpful.

Note: I do not want a dual boot at all. Only ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

For a modern one-user (or mainly one-user) workstation, partitioning is more a matter of taste than other thing. I commented more extensively [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/379212/16395).

If you are sure yo do not want other OS installed (even in the future), I would expand the `/home` partition to fill the disk (and maybe leaving a bit more space for `/`, although I never filled it up.)

My normal routine when installing from scratch is to create `/` and `/home`, and then moving `/usr/local` and `/opt` in the home partition, and then linking them back. Some on the line of (as root):

```
cp -rva /usr/local /home 
mv /usr/local /usr/local.old
ln -s /home/local /usr/local
```

and (normally `/opt` does not exist)

```
mkdir /home/opt 
ln -s /home/opt /opt
```

This kind of configuration will let you reinstall another Linux operating system without touching your data (even locally compiled programs will stay under `/home/local`, and you have to just re-do the links when reinstalling).

Another possibility (quite more complex, but interesting) is to [learn to use LVM](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuDesktopLVM):  : in that way you can resize the partition on the fly if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Partitioning is more an art then a science. Personally I would dedicate 40 Gb to your root partition, 40 Gb for /home and the rest in a back up or data partition. You can give it all to /home if you do not want a separate data partition.