# Recommended size in percentage for each partition

Tags: 12.04, disk-usage, partitioning

I have seen most of dedicated hosting companies servers always have multiple partition for various folders. I have tried to follow some guide lines on my own on virtual box. I always use swap space as double the ram. let's say

```
TS = total Size
SS = Swap Size
MS = Main Size

MS = TS - SS
```

What is bellow is percentage on MS.

```
/         20%
/boot     100M
/var      25%
/home     24%
/usr      10%
/tmp      200M
/opt      10%
```

it looks like I still need some key places I should give more space and some other places I should reduce space for example `/usr` and `/var`.

Your contribution would be greatly.

Answer (score 0):

```
/  100%
```

I'm serious.

The [only reason I could find](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#Benefits_of_multiple_partitions) for doing this in a hosting capacity is that it makes it easier to do partial backups. The host can just take live snapshots of the bits that change (`/var/`, `/home/`) and take slower backups of `/etc/` and pretty much everything else can be restored at install time.

It's by no means standard practice and you can do the same thing intelligently if you know where the data churn is... But to a big host this could mean terabytes of savings. With one virtual host, you're not saving anything. You're just giving yourself a headache.

Let the installer do what it wants to do unless you've got a really good reason.

Comment: I think that a personal workstation is quite different from a multiuser server... in the latter, for example, splitting out /tmp avoid users filling the system disk (maliciously or not). The same for the /var files. For a personal installation, I still advise for [`/` and `/home`](http://askubuntu.com/a/379019/16395) (for easy re-installations).

Comment: "For a personal installation, I still advise for / and /home (for easy re-installations)." I agree entirely and my / takes up remarkably little space, under 10GB, and I have lots of stuff installed. I wouldn't use 20% for / on, for example a 500GB HDD because that would leave a _lot_ of wasted space.

Comment: My `$HOME` lives on / proper and I just move the stuff I'd like to keep out to a RAID5 array and symlink it back. This is fairly trivial and means I'm not constrained to arbitrary limits... But I agree that it's okay for some people... But in the case of a VM?

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, but if any one you were to setup a server, how would you do it?