# Dual boot (Windows 10 + Ubuntu) - SSD+HDD - How to allocate more space from HDD

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I am trying to install Ubuntu and Windows 10 alongside for my college course, I don't have much experience with ubuntu, so bear with me if what I ask is too simple.

I have the Following setup
SSD - 465 GB

- 300 GB Allocated to Windows 10

HDD -  931 GB

- 730 GB Allocated to Windows

My course requires me to have 250-300 GB space in Ubuntu
I have Installed ubuntu (Dual Boot) on SSD as:

- 16 GB on '/swap'
- 145 GB on '/'

My SSD is fully allocated right now
I need to give atleast 100-150 GB space from HDD to ubuntu but I am not sure how to go about doing it

I just wanted to know how I could give more space to ubuntu so that I can setup softwares later without any problems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you will need 300GB for software. Almost certainly most of that will be needed for data. The simplest way to get more space on your system is to add a Linux partition (ext4 is a good format to use) to the HDD. Looks like you have about 200GB unallocated. You can use Gparted to make and format that partition. Then you add a new mount point somewhere like /data and add an entry to /etc/fstab to mount the new partition at boot time.

Alternatively you may be able to shrink your windows partition on the SSD and expand the Ubuntu partition. This is not too difficult to do but you may not be able to give up enough space from Windows.

There are plenty of detailed answers on Ask Ubuntu and on the wider internet about how to do these things but if you get stuck ask another question. Good luck with your course!

Comment: Example data partition(s). https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: I tried using Gparted without much success, was able to create a partition (200GB, ext4, labeled it as U). Then using 'disks', I mounted it on '/mnt/U'. The disk does show up when I go to the directory but I am not allowed to make changes (Idk why it is configured as read only or something like that). I have to use 'sudo' to create a directory in it which is not the best way to go about it.
I think gaining rights may solve the problem or should I change the mount directory to something inside home?

Comment: To solve your permissions issue search on google with “Linux chown”. There are plenty of guides available. Also research fstab. You can modify the /etc/fstab file to make your new partition mount automatically at boot. It is largely subjective where you mount the new partition. I find /data intuitive and the file path is short. If you need more help ask a new question about the specific issue.