# Brief Installation

Tags: 14.04, boot, partitioning, system-installation, boot-partition

I am using windows since i got into computers, so i thought Ubuntu would replace my interests in computer programming. Now i think its time to install Ubuntu (only) on my laptop. I have no idea about different partition methods. I wanted all files in the hard disk after installing Ubuntu. Now i know installing new OS will erase the installed programs, music, pictures and Downloads from windows. I don't know whether it erases all the data completely from the hard disk. Is it possible to keep the data after installing Ubuntu on windows?. If yes i want to know how to make partitions solely for Ubuntu and have it installed on my laptop.

Comment: Whatever you try, backup your data. Then you can read for example http://askubuntu.com/questions/516353/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-mounting-various-directories-on-sep, http://askubuntu.com/questions/379205/installing-programs-in-root-vs-home-partitions and the linked Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

You will have the option to partition when installing Ubuntu. Go to ubuntu.com, download the iso file, and make a new USB, e.g. with LinuxLive USB Creator(http://www.linuxliveusb.com/) Restart PC, and start from the newly created USB. Be careful to choose the option to partition your hard drive; don't format it. Your data from you're windows partition will be available for you then, if everything works out.

Good luck