# ubuntu disk partition in dual boot for use data science and android studio

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

My Lenovo legion laptop configuration is 1 tb ssd and 16 gb ram with nvidia grahics with preinstalled windows.I am dual booting with windows and Linux. I will do all my projects in ubuntu and windows will be only for casual use. I will be doing projects on ML Deep Learning  and android studio in ubuntu only.I am allocating 250 gb for ubuntu below .Which partition I should choose::

300gb - windows c drive;
450gb - D drive for personal data shareable for both OS;

For ubuntu 250 gb -(which one I should choose?)

**First:** /root - 100gb ; /home - 140; /swap - 8 gb;.

**second:**  /root - 70gb ; /home - 170; /swap - 8 gb;

/root or /home which one  need more space for  programs and projects
anything should I change in partition?. Do I need to add  efi for different boot loader to separate OS bootloader ?.

**OR ELSE**   I should choose option  ubuntu alongside windows option  while installing in 250 gb direct.
Do I need to add  efi for different boot loader ?.
Kindly help me in this installation confusion.

[image]

Comment: _SKB_, /swap's obsolete. Ever since kernel improvements in late 2017, swap files have been as fast as swap partitions, and they're much easier to expand when you find an app requires it, so when you install Ubuntu 18.04 or later, the installer makes a swap file for you.

Comment: Just be sure to boot installer in UEFI mode. I prefer to partition in advance and include an ESP - efi system partition on every drive. But it gets used more as place to backup ESP on first drive. The Ubiquity installer only installs grub to first drive it sees, usually into the ESP Windows has already created. Do not create duplicate ESP on same drive, only one per drive.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI  UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: I already have efi of 250 mb 
what should I choose manual partition by clicking "something else " OR option "ubuntu alongside window " which one please tell

Comment: thank you @k7AAY

Comment: thank you @oldfred

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `/` versus `/root` partitions

You need one `/` partition. This is often called System Root Partition. You don't normally need a separate `/root` partition. The `/root` is the "home" of the `root` user. In olden times Linux users used to login as `root`. Some still do. Local `root` login is disabled in Ubuntu by default for security reasons. I don't think you need a `/root` partition.

**You do need a `/` partition.** This is something similar to the "C Drive" in Windows. Without this partition Ubuntu won't install.

## `/` or `/home` which need more space?

It depends on what you plan to do with the computer.

### More Space in `/`

- If you want to run web servers or develop web pages or web based
  services, then `/` may need more space. **Note:** Some Machine Learning and Deep Learning tools work as web based services.
- If you play a lot
  of Linux native games or install a lot of Linux native applications,
  you need more space in `/`.

### More Space in `/home`

- All personal files, documents, music, videos, go to `/home`. You can put them in the shared NTFS partition (D Drive). See [Windows Ubuntu dual boot - Share files between OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223655/windows-ubuntu-dual-boot-share-files-between-os/223670#223670) for more.
- If you buy and play Steam games in Ubuntu, those games and the game
  data will go to `/home`.
- If you use **wine** to install Windows applications in Ubuntu, those
  software, and their data will all go to `/home`.

As a new user of Ubuntu you may not know yet which of these things you will be doing. Therefore, I recommend you do not create a separate `/home` partition. If you use the default Ubuntu installation then it will create a single `/` 250 GB partition. `/home` will be a folder in it. This will give you the most flexibility in terms of using Ubuntu.

See [What are the advantages and disadvantages of mounting various directories on separate partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/516353/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-mounting-various-directories-on-sep/516371#516371) for more.

## Swap Partition or File

Current versions of Ubuntu do not create a `swap` partition, and you should not either.

## EFI System Partition (ESP)

This partition should already exist in your 1 TB SSD, as this is the only drive and Windows came pre-installed in it. You don't need to mess with it. Ubuntu will install the `grub` bootloader and part of it will go to this partition **provided you booted the Live USB in UEFI mode**. More on this below. You don't need to create a new ESP or install a different bootloader.

## Something Else or Alongside Windows

I recommend the Install Ubuntu Alongside Windows. If you create an empty space 250 GB that is unallocated in Windows, then Ubuntu installer will find it and use it to create the 250 GB `/` partition.

## boot USB in UEFI mode

**This is very important.** When you select to boot from the Ubuntu Live USB (AKA the Ubuntu Installation USB), make sure you choose the one that says UEFI. You may see options like:

- Boot from internal drive
- Boot from USB
- Boot from USB UEFI

Choose the USB with UEFI. Ubuntu installation will work differently if you choose the wrong one. See [Installation problems with GRUB, can only install by reinstalling Windows in legacy mode but need to keep in UEFI mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134678/installation-problems-with-grub-can-only-install-by-reinstalling-windows-in-leg/1134955#1134955) for how to distinguish between the two, after you select USB boot.

Hope this helps

Comment: @Kulfy Thanks for the quick edit.

Comment: thank you sooo much